# Woocommerce disable reviews for specific product id

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to disable reviews for an specific product via php

Basically, I'm auto generating products based on a form using `wp_insert_post()`

I have the newly generated product ID, i just can't figure what function or parameter to change.

I don't need to disable reviews sitewide, just specific products

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lol, I figured it out.

Woocommerce treats "Reviews" as "Comments"

So when using `wp_insert_post()` there is a parameter as "comment_status" that can be set to open or closed

my codes looks like:

```
$prod_values = array (
    'post_author' => 'Custom Road Case',
    'post_content' => $case_content,
    'post_status' => "publish",
    'post_title' => $case_title,
    'post_type' => "product",
    'comment_status' => "closed",
);

$custom_case_id = wp_insert_post( $prod_values, __('Cannot create product', 'bones') );
```

Hope it helps somebody.